# Is there any possible way to extract the states of variables which causes the desirable execution path in a multi branch c program

Tags: c++, unit-testing, debugging

Consider the following code:

```
//global variables 

int x, y, z; 

// function prototypes


void updateGlobalVariables(void);
void func1(void);
void func2(void);
void func3(void);
void func4(void);

int main()
{

//changes the global variables
updateGlobalVariables();

if (x > 10) 
fun1();

else if (x<10 && y>10)
fun2();

else if (x>20 && y<30)
fun3();

else if (x>10 && z<10)
fun4();

}

void updateGlobalVariables(void)
{
 // update the global variables
}


void func1(void)
{
 // Do Something
}

void func2(void)
{
 // Do Something
}
void func3(void)
{
 // Do Something
}
void func4(void)
{
 // Do Something
}
```

Now, If I want to know the values of variables x,y and z which caused the function call sequence as - main -> func4

**Is there any way or tools to extract these information of the variables in large code with around 500-600 function calls with around 30-40 desirable function sequences?**

Comment: What does **function sequences** mean?

Comment: No -- the available tools are *human eyeballs*. There are tools that will extract the function names and logic paths, but not list the states of variables needed to take each path. [GNU cflow](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/cflow/) is one such tool.

Comment: **function sequences** means the function call graphs or sequence in which the functions are called according to various code conditions.

Comment: This technique is called **symbolic execution** and—unfortunately—all I know is the name, I have never used it.

Comment: Thank you @Dietrich Epp I will look at it

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your problem, but why don't you use a debugger, place a breakpoint and have a look at the call stack?

Comment: @schorsch312 I understand the question of the OP in that way: For any function like `func4` what are the possible values of `x`, `y` and `z` so that this function is called, and how can this determined automatically.

Comment: I suspect the problem is impossible in general because it implies the Halting Problem. Nonetheless, programs can be analyzed using the mathematics of formal semantics, and that will allow deriving conditions in “simple” cases. Software designed to assist in proving software correctness might be useful for this.

Comment: @ t.niese Yes, you are correct, that is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this does what you need but you could create a class that holds references to your global variables that you instantiate at the start of each function (using a macro).
It can then print the function name and the variable varlues when entering and exiting the function. It can also use a depth counter to be able to indicate how deep in the call chain the program is.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename... Args>
struct ctx {
    ctx(const char* file, const char* func, const Args&...args) :
        File(file), Func(func), m_args(args...)
    {
        std::cout << "-> " << *this;  // print -> when entering
        ++depth;
    }
    ~ctx() {
        --depth;
        std::cout << "<- " << *this;  // print <- when exiting
    }

    // print all the variable values
    template<typename T, T... ints>
    void print(std::ostream& os, std::integer_sequence<T, ints...>) const {
        os << std::string(depth, ' ') << File << ',' << Func << ':';
        ((os << ' ' << std::get<ints>(m_args)),...) << '\n';
    }

private:
    const char* const File;
    const char* const Func;
    std::tuple<const Args&...> m_args;  // holds references to your variables
    static thread_local unsigned depth; // call chain depth counter
};

template<typename... Args> thread_local unsigned ctx<Args...>::depth = 0;

// ostream proxy to call ctx::print
template<typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ctx<Args...>& c) {
    auto seq = std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{};
    c.print(os, seq);
    return os;
}

// a macro to be able to get __FILE__ and __func__ info into the class
#define CTX(...) ctx dummy_name(__FILE__,__func__,__VA_ARGS__)
```

The usage could be something like this:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

// helper macro for a common set of variables
#define CTXXYZ() CTX(x,y,z)

void func4(void) {
    CTXXYZ();
    ++z;
}

void func3(void) {
    CTXXYZ();
    ++y;
    func4();
}

void func2(void) {
    CTXXYZ();
    ++x;
    func3();
}

void func1(void) {
    CTXXYZ();
    ++x; ++y; ++z;
    func2();
}

int main() {
    func1();
}
```

Possible output:

```
-> ./example.cpp,func1: 0 0 0
->  ./example.cpp,func2: 1 1 1
->   ./example.cpp,func3: 2 1 1
->    ./example.cpp,func4: 2 2 1
<-    ./example.cpp,func4: 2 2 2
<-   ./example.cpp,func3: 2 2 2
<-  ./example.cpp,func2: 2 2 2
<- ./example.cpp,func1: 2 2 2
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oMMbeP)

Answer (score -1):

One way to debug this could be to add debug/log statements at the beginning of each function.

```
void func1(void)
{
    print("func1() was called."); //sample statement; replace with suitable logger or function
}
```

And you can see the trace in your output/terminal or if you used a logger, in your stack trace.

Comment: this would yield the output: like "main() was called", "func1() was called". But what i need is something like this: for sequence main() -> func1(), values of x = 11, y=1, z=1. something like this. And adding printf() function on every function (600 odd functions, with all the possible input variables) will be very tedious work and is highly prone to human errors.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? I don't get it.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment, Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Did you try using a Debugger, setting breakpoints, and setting watches for x, y, and z?

Comment: Yes it is one possible solution with using the debugger automation.